# We're trying to develop a game from the ground up in Java. What Technologies do we need?

Tags: java

My friend and I are trying our hands at 3D game development. We're both Java professionals, but not experts by any means. We know we want to use Java and we want to build everything in house including game engine, graphics engine and so on(we don't want to use the Unreal engine or Ogre3D or other pre-built engines). We want to kick off with the best toolkit possible. What IDE's, editors, source control, technologies do we need for everything from story-boarding to alpha-testing? Much Thanks.

Comment: You might have better luck here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Java professionals and asking for IDE and source control?

Comment: Voting to close, I think if you are Java professionals you are already comfortable with IDEs and source control - there are no *special* VCS for game development. As for technologies - if you want to build everything from scratch, Java SE is the only technology I can think of...

Comment: Also googling gives plenty of results on various forums.

Comment: You should also know that if you want to develop *everything*, you are going to be doing it for a *long* time. You should really consider using existing frameworks...

Comment: I am a bit confused by the question, "from scratch" and "best toolkit possible" are a bit at odds. Is using an opengl wrapper like jogl cheating? What about a general-purpose utility project like guava? As for IDE/editor/source control, use what you are comfortable with.

Comment: java professionals with 6 questions on SO and no answers?

Comment: As in do we want to use Swing or FX2 or Java 3D? What are the benefits/drawbacks of GIT vs Subversion, OpenGL vs DirectX and so on. Google searches are based on hits and traffic so all the books/tutorials/reviews are from 2003 and just keep getting re-hit so they clutter the top of the list. Thanks for the StackExchange link.

Comment: @hSherlock: Google searches are based on much more than hits and traffic. Also, StackOverflow isn't a one-stop place to have everything figured out for you, it's for specific technical questions.

Comment: @ColinD: Yeah that was a mistake on my part. I'll keep it in mind from now on.

Comment: @hSherlock Moreover, there ARE NO "best CVS", "best 3D API", "best game framework" etc. The reason there are several of those - because all of them are better at something. If a framework is worse in every aspect than other framework - it dies.

Comment: OK OK. Relax people. I was soliciting recommendations for things other people have used in the past that they've had good experiences with in order to avoid that "holy crap we have to port everything" phase when we realize we started working with something that's no good. I thought "What's the best way to ask the Java community a question?" Thrown in a shaker and put over some ice it turned into this which I have come to very much regret. I'm glad a few people had some constructive input or could tell me off with some professionalism, but wow this got out of hand.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ for IDE and GIT for source control would be my recommendations.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any preference on something like TurboCAD or Lightworks or Blender?